# Styling not refreshing for old visitors on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, sass

I’m working on correcting a styling of an element on an WP-based eCommerce site.

The site has both SCSS and CSS files.

To make things quick, I edited the CSS via Appearance -> Customize ->  Additional CSS.

However, when I was done and published my changes (and solved the issue), only those new to the website sees the difference.

Those who have visited the site prior to the deployment of the solution, still see the distorted number layout

I also suspected that the SCSS gets compiled every refresh but when I checked the File Manager (cPanel), only the CSS files get modified.

I’m feeling this might be a cache-related issue. I have already disabled a cache plugin (WP Rocket). However, the problem still persists.

What possible issue am I experiencing?

Edit: I did try to use Incognito and the change did reflect. However, the users of the site are non-techy people and don't know how to refresh.

The site is using GoDaddy as the host. Is it possible the issue is on that part?

Thank you

Comment: It's a cache issue for sure. There could be multiple sources of cache you need to purge the cache from every source, possible sources( WP Plugin, Server cache option, CDN cache ), and Test the website in Incognito Mode, if you're using your regular window and you're loggedin as admin then I will suggest trying force reloading the page.

Comment: @VijayHardaha Thank you for the reply. I did try to check on Incognito mode and the change did reflect. However, since typical users don't know how to clear cache, the problem for old visitors still persists. I'm using GoDaddy btw. Is it possible its on that side where the issue is coming from. 

Will also edit my question to give more clarity

Comment: Please check if GoDaddy has any cache option in the GoDaddy account/cPanel, if yes then clear the cache from there as well. Regarding the old visitors sometimes their browsers may take some time to load the fresh content. In that case, I don't think we can really do anything to force load new content.

Comment: There are also Wordpress plugins that prevent caching from happening in general, which means people wouldn't even need to clear it.